# How to store object data into file

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I'm making a program similar to a bank system, where it can read and store data from clients, and make transactions storing the information of them. Basically, I have lots of information stored in vectors and in many classes, and I would like to store them into files so I can read them later. Is there a way to do this easily than getting one by one and putting in a .txt file? I don't need the file to be readable by humans, by the way.

Comment: What have you tried to do exactly? Anything yet? For serializing to files, I often use the json format.

Comment: I was trying to get every information one by one and putting them into separate files. That worked pretty whell. My problem is to read the files, because i have to create many constructors and, besides the work, it may decrease safety and reliability. I searched for ways to do it in a more efficient way but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: That's a wide topic and it is called serialization. Use that as a search term. SO can't provide lectures on such a large topic, but come back if you have specific questions. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I was searching and i have read this term many times. I will search for it, thanks for the help!

Comment: This may be worth reading: [C++ FAQ: Serialization and Unserialization](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization).